# indexing for speeding up reading | mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, blob, sql-like

i've been asked the following question:

> For each of the following queries, design one or more indexes that
> would speed it up assuming the table(s) had enough rows. For each
> query submit SQL statements that add the index(es) to the relevant
> table(s) in alikas.
>
> a. `SELECT film_id, description FROM film  WHERE description LIKE 'A B ';`
>
> b. `SELECT film_id, description FROM film_text  WHERE description LIKE 'A B ';`
>
> c. `` SELECT f.film_id, f.title, a.last_update FROM film AS f  INNER JOIN film_actor AS fa  ON f.film_id = fa.film_id  INNER JOIN actor AS a  ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id WHERE f.rating = 'G' AND a.last_update `>= '2006-02-15 04:34:33'; ``

I tried to create an index on description column but got an error code 1770 : `BLOB/TEXT column 'description' used in key specification without a key length`

is it the right column to index for that purpose ? if so, how do I solve the problem? if not, what is the right column to index?

table is set by

```sql
CREATE TABLE `film` (
 `film_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

 `description` text,

 `release_year` year DEFAULT NULL,

 `language_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,

 `original_language_id` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,

 `rental_duration` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT ''3'',

 `rental_rate` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''4.99'',

 `length` smallint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,

 `replacement_cost` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''19.99'',

 `rating` enum(''G'',''PG'',''PG-13'',''R'',''NC-17'') DEFAULT ''G'',

 `special_features` set(''Trailers'',''Commentaries'',''Deleted Scenes'',''Behind the Scenes'') DEFAULT NULL,

 `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

 PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`),

 KEY `idx_title` (`title`),

 KEY `idx_fk_language_id` (`language_id`),

 KEY `idx_fk_original_language_id` (`original_language_id`),

 CONSTRAINT `fk_film_language` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`language_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,

 CONSTRAINT `fk_film_language_original` FOREIGN KEY (`original_language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`language_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1002 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

thank you!

Comment: The question is incomplete. Please include the tables' definition.

Comment: Why don't you specify the key length?

Comment: @TheImpaler, edited, is there anything else I should specify?

Comment: @Jov When creating an index that has a member of the `TEXT` data type (as `description`) databases in general only index the first characters of it; MySQL is asking you how many characters of `description` you want to index. For example, if you want an index based on the first 50 characters, you can do: `create index ix1 on film (description(50));`. For performance reasons, you can't index the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Query 3 is a bit tricky.

The Optimizer will probably ponder whether to start with `f.rating = 'G'` or with `a.last_update` >= '2006-02-15 04:34:33'`.  It will decide based on limited knowledge about the distribution of data in the tables` f`and`a`.

If it starts with `f`, such as when the requested rating occurs in very few rows:

```
f:  INDEX(rating)
fa:  INDEX(film_id,  actor_id)
a:  INDEX(last_update)
```

If it starts with `a`, such as when the date range is narrow:

```
a:  INDEX(last_update, actor_id)
fa:  INDEX(actor_id, film_id)
f:  INDEX(rating, film_id)
```

Combining them, I recommend:

```
f:  INDEX(rating, film_id)       -- (handles both cases)
fa:  INDEX(film_id, actor_id)
fa:  INDEX(actor_id, film_id)    -- (yes both orderings)
a:  INDEX(last_update, actor_id)
a:  INDEX(actor_id, last_update) -- (yes both orderings)
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql